# ipvs status and netns?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipvs

Is the IPVS effort dead?  I can't find docs newer than 2011, and most docs are ca. 2004.

It does some interesting things, and I'd like to figure out how to make it work across netns.  Specificallty, I want to set up ipvs in the root netns and have docker containers access the VIPs, without programming them into each docker container's netns.

Any clues?

Answer (score -1):

IPVS is alive and well.  The documentation is "old" because it hasn't changed much since then, and it doesn't change much because it's already Freaking Awesome.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see it is still part of the current [main kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/ipvs?id=refs/tags/v4.2-rc6) and actively maintained there but apparently the API is so mature and stable the [documentation and tooling](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html) do not need much maintenance.